# how to mock session in Python's request library?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-requests

I have been trying to figure out how exactly to mock the session of Python's request library but couldn't find a solution till now. Here's my code of common.py that i need to write a test for:

```
import requests

def request_url(method, url):
    return _request_url(method, url)

def _request_url(method, url):
    session = requests.session()
    adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
    session.mount("https://", adapter)
    return session.request(method, url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mock the whole `_request_url` function, and not bother with the session object. All that the function does is provide a response object, *mock that function and return a mock response object*.

However, if you are testing the `_request_url` function *itself*, then just mock the `session` name; the additional calls will all be passed to the mock. You can then provide a response object of your choosing for the `mocked.return_value.rquest.return_value` object.

So

```
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch('requests.session') as mock_session:
    session_instance = mock_session.return_value
    mock_response = session_instance.request.return_value

    response = _request_url('METHOD', 'some url')

    assert response is mock_response
    session_instance.mount.assert_called()
    session_instance.request.assert_called_with('METHOD', 'some url')
```

or in a `TestCase` method:

```
@mock.patch('requests.session')
def test_request_url(self,  mock_session):
    session_instance = mock_session.return_value
    mock_response = session_instance.request.return_value

    response = _request_url('METHOD', 'some url')

    self.assertTrue(response is mock_response)
    session_instance.mount.assert_called()
    session_instance.request.assert_called_with('METHOD', 'some url')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> import requests, ssl
>>> class TlsAdapter:
...     # mocked adapter, just for illustration purposes
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): pass
...
>>> def _request_url(method, url):
...     session = requests.session()
...     adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
...     session.mount("https://", adapter)
...     return session.request(method, url)
...
>>> with mock.patch('requests.session') as mock_session:
...     session_instance = mock_session.return_value
...     mock_response = session_instance.request.return_value
...     response = _request_url('METHOD', 'some url')
...     assert response is mock_response
...     session_instance.mount.assert_called()
...     session_instance.request.assert_called_with('METHOD', 'some url')
...
>>> # nothing happened, because the test passed, no assertion errors were raised
...
```

Comment: @HussainAliAkbar: there is no 'session' to patch, no, because there is no such module. Use the full name, so `requests.session`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @MartijnPieters ! I'll try this and see if it works for me.

Comment: a follow up question, if i want to add a side effect rather than a normal return value such as redirection 302 rather than 200, then how can i do that?  I know that i have to somehow set the mock_session.side_effect value but i cant seem to figure out how to do that. Can this be answered here or do i need to ask another question? Thanks!

Comment: i went ahead and asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148452/how-to-mock-side-effects-in-session-in-pythons-request-library

Comment: My day just started, I'll answer there.