# How to mock side effects in session in Python's request library?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

This is a followup to a question that I asked [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128015/how-to-mock-session-in-pythons-request-library#49128015).

I am trying to mock a session of the `requests` library. While I got my answer as to how to mock a successful return value, I am still trying to figure out how to mock side effects such as 400, 401, or 302 etc.

This is how I am mocking a session:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> import requests, ssl
>>> class TlsAdapter:
...     # mocked adapter, just for illustration purposes
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): pass
...
>>> def _request_url(method, url):
...     session = requests.session()
...     adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
...     session.mount("https://", adapter)
...     return session.request(method, url)
...
>>> with mock.patch('requests.session') as mock_session:
...     session_instance = mock_session.return_value
...     mock_response = session_instance.request.return_value
...     response = _request_url('METHOD', 'some url')
...     assert response is mock_response
...     session_instance.mount.assert_called()
...     session_instance.request.assert_called_with('METHOD', 'some url')
```

Now, as far as I have read, I need to mock `session_instance.request.side_effect`. If I try to do something like this, it fails:

```
    response_redirect = mock.MagicMock()
    response_redirect.status_code = 302
    response_redirect.headers = {"location": "https://absolute"}

    session_instance.request.side_effect = response_redirect
    response = _request_url('METHOD', 'https://absolute')
    self.assertEqual(result, response_redirect)

    #Assertion error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a side effect. Your 'redirect' response is just another return value for the `session.request` call. Set your attributes on the `mock_return` reference:

```
mock_response = session_instance.request.return_value
mock_response.status_code = 302
mock_response.headers = {"location": "https://absolute"}

response = _request_url('METHOD', 'http://absolute')
```

Use `.side_effects` for when you need to:

- raise exceptions
- handle multiple calls (you can set `side_effects` to a sequence of return values to produce, used in order).
- need to have access to the values that have been passed to the call (you can set `side_effect` to a function that'll be called with the same arguments).

**However**: if the code you are testing is `_request_url()`, then it *should not matter* if the request resulted in a redirect or not. The code in `_request_url()` is entirely indifferent to what kind of response is being returned, so why should you need to test for that at all?

If, on the other hand you are testing code that *uses* `_request_url()` as a utility function, then you should be mocking *that function*, and not the `requests` library.

Comment: Thanks! This helps so much yet again!